# Count number of dots in bitmap

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have an Image in which there are 6 (one pixel each) white dots with R=240, G=240, B=240 like below Image.

I am calculating color value for each pixel by using below code but the problem is this method is not giving exact result.

Am i doing the right method? If yes why this method is not giving exact result? Thanks in advance.

```
int getDotCount(Bitmap bm) {
        int count = 0;

        final int width = bm.getWidth();
        final int height = bm.getHeight();

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                //RGB value for dot is 240
                if (Color.red(pixel) == 240 &&
                        Color.red(pixel) == Color.blue(pixel) &&
                        Color.red(pixel) == Color.green(pixel)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks correct for me, there seems to be another problem.

Comment: Could it be that each dot is actually 4 pixels big?

Comment: ya i can make 4 pixel for each dot. But can you tell me the reason?

Comment: No. I don't know where you got the bitmap from and how the dots came onto it. Your code counts pixels, not dots.

Comment: First of all i am setting drawable into a image view and then i am pulling bitmap from it to calculate the dots.

Comment: Could you add the following line just after `count++`: `System.out.println('Found white dot at ("+x+", "+y+")");` to see where the extra dots are?

Comment: @StephaneM if i put pixel of dot=2 then it gives more than expected result. But in above case (1 dot = 1 pixel) it is giving 0 count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing long research i finally figure out my problem. I was putting above image inside `drawable` folder and it was scaled by Android. To avoid scaling of an image i put it in `drawable-nodpi`. It solve my problem.

Thank you all of you who tried to help me. Cheers!!!